# pandas index skipping values

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I'm reading in two csv files, selecting data from a specific column, dropping NA/nulls, and then using the data that fits some condition in one file to print the associated data in another:

```
data1 = pandas.read_csv(filename1, usecols = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']).dropna()
data2 = pandas.read_csv(filename2, usecols = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']).dropna()
i=0
for item in data1['Y']:
    if item > -20:
        print data2['X'][i]
```

But this throws me an error:

```
File "hashtable.pyx", line 381, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:7035)
File "hashtable.pyx", line 387, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:6976)
KeyError: 6L
```

Turns out when I `print data2['X']` I see missing numbers in the index of rows

```
0    -1.953779
1    -2.010039
2    -2.562191
3    -2.723993
4    -2.302720
5    -2.356181
7    -1.928778
...
```

How do I fix this and renumber the index values? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution in another question from here: [Reindexing dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557542/reindexing-dataframes)

`.reset_index(drop=True)` does the trick!

```
0    -1.953779
1    -2.010039
2    -2.562191
3    -2.723993
4    -2.302720
5    -2.356181
6    -1.928778
7    -1.925359
```

Answer (score 1):

Are your two files/dataframes the same length? If so, you can leverage boolean masks and do this (and it avoids a for loop):

```
data2['X'][data1['Y'] > -20]
```

Edit: in response to the comment

What happens in between:

```
In [16]: df1
Out[16]:
   X  Y
0  0  0
1  1  2
2  2  4
3  3  6
4  4  8

In [17]: df2
Out[17]:
    Y   X
0  64  75
1  65  73
2  36  44
3  13  58
4  92  54

# creates a pandas Series object of True/False, which you can then use as a "mask"
In [18]: df2['Y'] > 50
Out[18]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
Name: Y, dtype: bool

# mask is applied element-wise to (in this case) the column of your DataFrame you want to filter
In [19]: df1['X'][ df2['Y'] > 50 ]
Out[19]:
0    0
1    1
4    4
Name: X, dtype: int64

# same as doing this (where mask is applied to the whole dataframe, and then you grab your column
In [20]: df1[ df2['Y'] > 50 ]['X']
Out[20]:
0    0
1    1
4    4
Name: X, dtype: int64
```

Comment: So it would return all of the values in data2['X'] at the same index as the values in data1['Y'] that were greater than -20? Definitely cleaner than my for loop method. Thanks for sharing, always great to learn about new/different approaches