# Resetting index after calling pandas drop_duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to open a file, read it, drop duplicates in two of the file's columns, and then further use the file without the duplicates to do some calculations. To do this I am using pandas.drop_duplicates, which after dropping the duplicates also drops the indexing values. For example after droping line 1, file1 becomes file2:

```
file1:
   Var1    Var2    Var3   Var4
0    52     2       3      89
1    65     2       3      43
2    15     1       3      78
3    33     2       4      67

file2:
   Var1    Var2    Var3   Var4
0    52     2       3      89
2    15     1       3      78
3    33     2       4      67
```

To further use file2 as a dataframe I need to reindex it to 0, 1, 2, ...

Here is the code I am using:

```
file1 = pd.read_csv("filename.txt",sep='|', header=None, names=['Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3', 'Var4']) 
file2 = file1.drop_duplicates(["Var2", "Var3"])
# create another variable as a new index: ni
file2['ni']= range(0, len(file2)) # this is the line that generates the warning
file2 = file2.set_index('ni')
```

Although the code runs and produces good results, reindexing, gives the following warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  file2['ni']= range(0, len(file2))
```

I did check the link but I cannot figure out how to change my code. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: [starting from pandas 2.0, `drop_duplicates` supports `ignore_index=True`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.Series.drop_duplicates) so you can skip the `reset_index` call ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76020841/4909087))

Answer (score 28):

[Pandas has a built in function to accomplish this task](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), which will allow you to avoid the thrown error by means of an alternative, and simpler, approach

Rather than adding a new column of sequential numbers and then setting the index to that column as you did with:

```
file2['ni']= range(0, len(file2)) # this is the line that generates the warning
file2 = file2.set_index('ni')
```

You can instead use:

```
file2 = file2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

The default behavior of `.reset_index()` is to take the current index, insert that index as the first column of the dataframe, and then build a new index (I assume the logic here is that the default behavior makes it very easy to compare the old vs. new index, very useful for sanity checks). `drop=True` means instead of preserving the old index as a new column, just get rid of it and replace it with the new index, which seems like what you want.

all together, your new code could look like this

```
file1 = pd.read_csv("filename.txt",sep='|', header=None, names=['Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3', 'Var4']) 
file2 = file1.drop_duplicates(["Var2", "Var3"]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

[See this question as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557542/reindexing-dataframes)

Comment: Instead of resetting index in the next step (`.reset_index(drop=True)`), you can add another attribute into `drop_duplicates()`: `ignore_index=True`

Answer (score 4):

I think your `.drop_duplicates()` is actually causing the warning.

Instead make sure you make a new copy of the dataframe:

```
file2 = file1.drop_duplicates(["Var2", "Var3"]).copy()
```

Answer (score 3):

#### pandas >= 2.0: [`drop_duplicates` now supports `ignore_index=True`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.Series.drop_duplicates)

pandas >= 2.0

```
df.drop_duplicates(["Var2", "Var3"], ignore_index=True)

   Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4
0    52     2     3    89
1    15     1     3    78
2    33     2     4    67
```

This allows you to skip the follow up `reset_index` call.

Implemented in [GH48304](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/48304)

---

for older pandas versions (< 2.0)

```
df.drop_duplicates(["Var2", "Var3"]).reset_index(drop=True)

   Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4
0    52     2     3    89
1    15     1     3    78
2    33     2     4    67
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set `ignore_index` parameter of [pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas-dataframe-drop-duplicates) to `True` to reindex the resulting DataFrame. By default, it's value is `False`.

So, your code

```py
file1 = pd.read_csv("filename.txt",sep='|', header=None, names=['Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3', 'Var4']) 
file2 = file1.drop_duplicates(["Var2", "Var3"])
# create another variable as a new index: ni
file2['ni']= range(0, len(file2)) # this is the line that generates the warning
file2 = file2.set_index('ni')
```

will be updated to

```py
file1 = pd.read_csv("filename.txt",sep='|', header=None, names=['Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3', 'Var4']) 
file2 = file1.drop_duplicates(["Var2", "Var3"], ignore_index=True)
```